# I keep seeing "Failed to send host log message" in my Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bootloader

Whenever I try to boot into my Ubuntu VM, I keep getting an error saying "*ERROR* Failed to send host log message." I used to get this a lot and it would boot up completely fine, but now it just stays like this.
[VM Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYdle.png)

Comment: Try booting in recovery mode........   https://linuxhint.com/boot-ubuntu-into-recovery-mode/ .....  If you manage to fix the machine DO make a backup so you can recover from an error more readlly.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh and https://askubuntu.com/a/817660/1210606 Oh, the things we find just googling an error message...